# request error 400 while using python requests.post function

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am trying to make a minecraft name sniper which changes the name of an account as soon as the name is available. You basically enter in the information then run it seconds before the name is available. Then it should send multiple requests to change the username to the "target" username. However the requests come with the error 400.

```
import requests

username = input("username: ")
password = input("password: ")
bearer_key = input("Bearer Key: ")
target = input("Target Username: ")
useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4145.106 Safari/537.36'

us = req=requests.get(f'https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/agent/minecraft/name/{username}').json()
profileid = us['id']
print(profileid)


auth = 'Bearer ' + bearer_key
snipe = 0
while snipe < 100:
    s = requests.post(f'https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/{profileid}/name', headers={'Authorization': auth,'User-Agent': useragent}, json={"name": username,"password": password})
    print(s.status_code)



    if s.status_code == 204:
                            print(f'{username} is now yours!')
                            snipe = snipe + 100
    else:
        snipe = snipe + 1
        print(f"{snipe} retrying")
```

This is the code I am using to change the name and im getting the error 400. I know the error is with the requests.post line but i cant figure out what is wrong.

Edit:

````
import requests

username = input("username: ")
password = input("password: ")
uuid = input("UUID: ")
bearer = input("Bearer Key: ")
wanted_name = input("Target Username: ")

snipe = 0
while snipe < 100:
   url = 'http://api.mojang.com/user/profile/' + uuid + '/name'
   req = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization' : bearer,}, json={"name": wanted_name, "password": password})
   print(req.status_code)


   if req.status_code == 204:
                           print(f'{username} is now yours!')
                           snipe = snipe + 100
   else:
       snipe = snipe + 1
       print(f"{snipe} retrying")
   ```
````

Comment: An http code 400 means 'bad request', the server cannot process your request correctly as there is something wrong with it. This could be some missing field in the header, the payload, some error in the URL, etc. It's impossible to tell from your code alone, but you should either check the documentation of the service or compare to a request that does get processed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I don't think you are using the proper post method. Here's what you should be using:

```
url = 'http://api.mojang.com/user/profile/' + uuid + '/name'
req = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization': bearer}, json={"name": wanted_name,"password": password})
```

Here's a [link](https://wiki.vg/Authentication) that you can use to understand how to make requests to Mojang.

This is another [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) that will be helpful in understanding the different HTTP Status codes and their meanings.

Another little edit I had is to have the user enter the UUID, rather than making a get request. Personally, it makes sense to me, since the UUID is constant and will never change like the bearer does (I'm sure you know you can find this on NameMC).

Additionally, I think some things you should look into to make this sniper better are: the threading, asyncio, and json packages. These will probably better your performance of the bot as well.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have changed the UUID to make it so the user enters it and updated the post method. However when i try change a name it comes up with the status code 401. I understand it means unauthorized but I am sure I am using the correct info and bearer token.

Comment: The 401 error most likely came because of invalid credentials. Are you aware that bearer tokens only last for 1 minute with Mojang now? Try to log into an SFA and go for a low search name. That would test if the bot actually runs properly. Then use the methods I provided to make the bot even faster.

Comment: I tried many times with a sfa account and tried to change the name to any name that is available. However I am still getting the 401 status code. My new code is under Edit: in the original post. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Sure. This new edit seems good to me - maybe use a ```While true``` loop and break it when the name is sniped with ```ctrl + c```. Besides this, I really can't tell you anything else other than check your credentials. How are you inputting the bearer token?

Comment: I think the issue is that after 600 requests you get rate limited because  now when i tried some hours later it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds great! If this solution helped you, mark it as the answer so this post can have an answer. :)